# MySQL not Starting in AMPPS

Tags: mysql, ampps

I have installed AMPPS in my windows 10(64 bit) local machine.
When Starting, Apache and PHP have started but MySQL is not starting.

I tried some solutions from [this page](https://gist.github.com/irazasyed/c516682e34068b14b55d)

But nothing seems to work.

Answer (score 13):

I have the same problem and the solution with `innodb_force_recovery = 1` didn't work. When I run `/ampps/mysql/bin/mysql.exe` it was written that MSVCR100.dll was missing.
I solve that by installing Visual C++ 2010 Runtime, both 32bit and 64bit versions, from url:

32Bit: Microsoft Visual C++ 2010 SP1 Redistributable Package (x86)
http://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=8328

64Bit: Microsoft Visual C++ 2010 SP1 Redistributable Package (x64)
 
http://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=13523

This works for me and mysql start working :)

Comment: This is the best answer I’ve found anywhere. Thanks!

Comment: **Download the 32-bit version as AMPPS is 32-bit.**

Comment: AMPSS 3.8 includes redist 2017 but it seems that mysql need 2010 :)

Answer (score 5):

This works!!!

Install Visual C++ 2010 Runtime, both 32bit and 64bit versions, from url:

32Bit: Microsoft Visual C++ 2010 SP1 Redistributable Package (x86)
http://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=8328

64Bit: Microsoft Visual C++ 2010 SP1 Redistributable Package (x64)
http://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=13523

Answer (score 3):

i deleted these two files mysql.sock.lock,mysqlx.sock.lock  under var folder and it worked

Answer (score 1):

open `Ampps/mysql/data/` folder and delete all files similar to this ib_logfile and mysql-bin,ibdata, etc then start or restart MySQL via the AMPPS.

Answer (score 0):

i was having the same issue but no solution from internet worked,
most of the people suggesting to fix issue by removing mysql data or un/install software.
Anyway i fixed it myself after simple experiment.
I simply clicked on "mysql.exe" first and it did tells me that i have missing "msvcr100.dll" file.
Download from here : https://www.dll-files.com/msvcr100.dll.html
Also there was one more problem when i clicked on "mysqld.exe" it did tells me that i have missing msvcp100.dll file.
Download again from  : https://www.dll-files.com/msvcp100.dll.html
After i have downloaded all files
and put them in folder "path_to_your/Ampps/mysql/bin"
where "mysql.exe" and "mysqld.exe" reside,
then finally i was able to start the MySQL server.

This solution is only for system Windows.

Comment: **Download the 32-bit version of dll files
 as AMPPS is 32-bit.**

Answer (score 0):

- Search for [mysqld] section.
- Add following line below [mysqld] section:

```
innodb_force_recovery = 1
```

- Save configuration and restart MySQL.
- Now Stop MySQL.
- Remove the line just added and start MySQL again.

Answer (score 0):

After various tries, I just clicked on "restore default configuration" and i made it again to work.

[image]